# Query is not returning the correct result

Tags: sql

When I run the following query, I will get a result but it is not looking correct to me. So there must be a mistake somewhere in it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM fe_users 
INNER JOIN user_managementsg_user_table AS umut ON 
         fe_users.uid = umut.fe_id 
     AND fe_users.city = 'Bern' 
      OR fe_users.city = 'Basel' 
      OR fe_users.city = 'Solothurn' 
      OR fe_users.city = 'Aargau' 
     AND umut.funktion = 'Assistenzarzt' 
      OR umut.fachgebiet_rheumatologie = 1 
      OR umut.taetigkeitsfeld = 'Praxis'
```

**This is what I want:**

`fe_users.city` is either Bern OR Basel OR Solothurn OR Aargau

AND

Either `umut.funktion` is = 'Assistenzarzt' OR `umut.fachgebiet_rheumatologie` = 1 OR umut.taetigkeitsfeld = 'Praxis'

When I run my query above, some values of the column `city` are just different than the 4 cities that I have defined. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Do `fe_users.city in ('Bern', 'Basel', ...)`. Or put parentheses around the OR's.

Comment: Just for readability alone, you should add some parenthesis around your where cases.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @jarlh thank you, that helped me!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM fe_users 
INNER JOIN user_managementsg_user_table AS umut 
ON fe_users.uid = umut.fe_id 
AND (fe_users.city in ('Bern','Basel','Solothurn','Aargau') 
AND (umut.funktion = 'Assistenzarzt' OR umut.fachgebiet_rheumatologie = 1 OR umut.taetigkeitsfeld = 'Praxis')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM    fe_users
            INNER JOIN user_managementsg_user_table AS umut ON fe_users.uid = umut.fe_id
                                                            Where fe_users.city IN('Bern'
                                                               ,'Basel'
                                                               ,'Solothurn'
                                                               , 'Aargau')
                                                               AND (umut.funktion in('Assistenzarzt') OR umut.fachgebiet_rheumatologie = 1   OR umut.taetigkeitsfeld = 'Praxis'))
```